# Gerar arquivo de texto do Codigo feito em Pascal

Tags: pascal, txt

Tenho um código em pascal. É o seguinte:

```
Program Pzim ;
   var
     i:integer;
     vect:array[1..1001] of integer;
Begin
     i:=1;
     for i:= 1 to 999 do
     vect[i]:=i+1;
     for i:= 1 to 999 do
     writeln (vect[i]);
   readln;
End.
```

O código no Pascalzim imprime na tela uma sequencia de números.
Eu queria salvar em arquivo de texto o que for gerado pelo código.

seria possível usando o pascal mesmo, ou quem sabe de outra forma, usando o notepad++ por exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri! minha pergunta foi respondida no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386314/saving-text-file-from-code/35386527#35386527)

O codigo ficou assim:

```
Program Pascal ;

var
  i:integer;
  vect:array[1..1001] of integer;
  Myfile: text;

begin
  i:=1;
  for i:= 1 to 999 do
    vect[i]:=i+1;

  Assign(Myfile, 'Myfile.txt');
  Rewrite(MyFile);

  for i:= 1 to 999 do
  begin
    WriteLn (vect[i]);
    WriteLn(Myfile, vect[i]);
  end;
  Close(Myfile);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Um pequeno melhoramento que traz um aprendizado no tocante a organização da impressão do resultado.

```
Program Pascal ;

var
  i, j:integer;
  vect:array[1..1000] of integer;
  Myfile: text;

begin
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    vect[i] := j + 1;
        j := j + 1;
  end;

  Assign(Myfile, 'Myfile.txt');
  Rewrite(MyFile);

  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    if i < 1000 then
        begin   
        Write(vect[i], ', ');
        Write(Myfile, vect[i], ', ');
    end else begin
        Write(vect[i], '. ');
        Write(Myfile, vect[i], '.');
    end;
  end;

  Close(Myfile);
  ReadLn;
end.
```